# How to create a queue (that keeps the queued msgs saved after the application shutdown) in android?

Tags: android, queue

I am trying to figure out the best way to implement queue that keep the queued msgs saved after the application shutdown in Android. My use case is my  application needs to post json requests to the server and if one failed my application will try again after 5 min using alarm manager so the application could die and then brought back to life using  broadcast receiver, thats why i need to save the msgs.

Comment: I think you need to use either database (or) file system to store your message when your app crashes. May be by assigning a priority number for each message, once your app is back, check in database/file and process those messages in order. AFAIK there is no way to keep them in memory.

Comment: Do you think i could use shared preference ? and if so is there way to lock it to prevent old edited copy to overwrite new one ?

Comment: Yes you can use SharedPrefernces. SharedPreferences.Editor class can help you in adding content to sharedpreferences and removing content from sharedpreferences. I am not favorable to change preferences for this purpose. Prefernces are for their own purpose.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, you can store the messages in SharedPreferences by serializing the queue of messages and storing them as a string. But personally I would discourage storing that data in SharedPreferences because that's not what it's intended for. Android has SQLite built right in, so it would be really easy to store the messages in a small table like thinksteep suggested.